# Run a standard set controller extension from execute anonymous

Tags: apex, standardsetcontroller, execute-anonymous, gack

I am trying to run a standard set controller extension from execute anonymous for the purpose of debugging, however I keep getting "Internal Salesforce.com error".

I have narrowed down the offending code to the following:

```
Account a = new Account(Id = 'SOME_ACCOUNT_ID');
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
    new List<Account> { a }
);
```

And simplifying it even further yields the same error:

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
    new List<Account>()
);
```

Is there something that I am missing, or does this look like a Salesforce bug?

Answer (score 2):

The second error is from simplifying to the point that the list is a new, empty, list.

The first is probably because you did not insert the Account - you may have more luck with this:

```
Account a = new Account();
insert a;
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
    new List<Account> { a }
);
```

Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately that also gives the same error. Inserting the Account populates the Id which is effectively the same as instantiating a new Account SObject by passing an ID for an existing record.